# C++ bitwise XOR operator?

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli

I stumbled upon this code and don't understand the **`^`** operator in the **`string ^name`** declaration.
I found on google that it is a **bitwise XOR** operator but can't see the relevance here:

> ref class Animal{
>
> int legs;
>
> String ^name;
>
> };

Comment: You are looking at C++/CLI (by Microsoft) source code. Where `^` is used to declare reference variables.

Comment: @BrianBi so it is Visual C++ then

Comment: @ChrisDobkowski, Visual C++ is a compiler, not a language. It can compile C++/CLI (although this could just as easily be C++/CX if I'm right), but your language tag said C++.

Comment: @max-m oh :/ sorry then, should of looked better. I just didn't knew even how it was called.

Comment: @ChrisDobkowski I found it when googling for "C++ caret" ^^